# Getting Parent TR of mutli-select element

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I have a table-based form, with two multi-select controls (that are also in tables), based on the value in a ddl, I'd like to show/hide the row containing the multi-select controls.

however, i found my code only toggles the inner table row. What I'd really like is for the outer table's row to be toggled. i thought using parent might work, but it didn't.

BTW.I also tried parent().parent().toggle(), but for some reason that wasn't working either.

Here's the HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <select> //numero
       <option>Uno</option>
       <option>Dos</option> 
     </select>
  </tr>
  <tr> <-- hide this row when Uno is chosen
     <table> //multi-select control table
    <tr></tr> <-- this is the row that is being hidden when i toggle() Uno
     </table>
  </tr>
  <tr> <-- another row i want to toggle when Dos is chosen
     <table> //multi-select control table
    <tr></tr> <-- this is the row that is being hidden when i toggle()
     </table>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my jQuery

```
 $("select[title='Numero']").change(function(){
     $("select[title='hide this row']").closest("tr").next("tr").toggle();
     $("select[title='another row i want to toggle']").closest("tr").toggle();
 }); //close Numero.change()
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your real html ?

Comment: Can you give us a more complete html example? Your selectors don't match any elements, and I'm having trouble following the comments and arrows.

Comment: I would suggest putting a class on the row(s) you want to toggle to make selecting them easier.

Comment: j08691, I can't use classes, b/c the html code is being generated by SharePoint.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JustJill54/pB9Pu/

Comment: @Jason P, 
I posted my fiddle above with more complete html. I was thinking that perhaps using .eq(#) might be able to work in this case, or .parentsUntil. However I can't seem to get either working on my example. What are your thoughts?
Thanks~ Jg